# Firebase - How to set security rules so that only logged in users can read and write?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

Firebase - How to set *security rules* so that only logged in users can read and write for a specific table?

For the logins I'm using firebase built in authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check on the `auth` variable

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "$post_id": {
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Check out the Firebase Security Guide for more information.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html)

[Also, you may want to check out the Bolt compiler.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/quickstart.html)

Comment: I had the other question you had posted, and answered that here. This is the modified answer to this question.

Comment: could you include his other post? Because I am wondering what If I want to do exactly what he wants but want teh Auth user to be able to read and write to any part of teh database.

Answer (score 3):

by changing the rules as follows

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```